# Create a table or view from EXEC statement SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, view, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

```
EXEC('Select
          trim(field1) field1
          CVDATE(date1) date1
      from tabel1
      where trim(field1) <> 'ABC' ') at AE  --linked server
```

I need to dump the result generated from EXECUTION statement into a view. Is this possible? I am guessing the query is written this way is due to performance reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [openquery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) to run the SELECT on remote server and create a view from the result set.

Here is a code sample. The sample creates `local1` as the linked server and executes the query on it. If you already have your linked server registered, you don't need to run the step 1 and 4.

```
-- Step 1. register a linked server
exec sp_addlinkedserver 
        @server = 'local1',
        @srvproduct = '',
        @provider='SQLNCLI',
        @datasrc = 'NameOfTheRemoteServer' -- if server has multiple instances use 'NameOfTheServer\NameOfTheInstance'
go

-- Step 2. run the query on remote server and create a view out of the results
create view ViewTest
as
select * from openquery(
    local1, 
    'select 
        top 10 
        lower(AddressLine1) as Street,
        ModifiedDate as dt
    from AdventureWorks2014.Person.Address'
    )
go

-- Step 3. check the view
select * from ViewTest
go

-- Step 4. finally drop the linked server
sp_dropserver 'local1'
go
```